# Twilio Phone Poll Call

Tags: twilio

we have integrated Phone Poll in our Website, But when originating the call to a number, by default call made 3 times, but we want to control the call from default 3 times to either only one or two or more than 3 times. how is it possible?

Comment: Twilio evangelist here.  Not sure I understand what your trying to build.  Can you explain a bit more?

Comment: actually i m working on a project having phone poll integration. starting with making call to different clients and getting there feedback.  now at first call client can do 3 things one is avoid the call second can recieve the call but pressing wrong entry instead of '1' which is required to press by the client, now third one is by pressing '1' to complete the call, but my issue is that suppose someone choose second or third things then the next call must come after the second and third things occur, which is not happened, because next comes quickly after the first call. how do i solve issue?

Comment: OK, so let me see if I understand.  You want to create a phone polling app.  When you make an outbound call to your customer you prompt them with three options: (1) ignore the call (eg not answer), (2) answer and press 1 or (3) answer and press something other than 1.  Your question is how to handle the 2nd and 3rd options?  I'm not clear by what you mean when you say "the next call comes quickly after the first".  Are you making more than one phone call to your customer?

Comment: when making an outbound call, it will calling 3 times by default?

Comment: OK so you are making 3 separate outbound calls.  I'm not sure I understand why you are doing that.

Comment: i have only one option '1' - 'Confirm'

Comment: no only one call, but it is calling 3 times to same number, repeating the same call

Comment: $client->account->calls->create("+xxxx", "+xxx", "URL",parameter);

Answer (score 0):

Twilio evangelist here.

It sounds like you are making three calls to your customer all at the same time.  I'm not sure why you are doing that, but I suspect what you want to do instead is wait for the first call to complete, then if needed make a second and possibly third call.

There are a couple ways to know if the call completes or not.  When you make your first outbound call, you can include the [StatusCallback](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/rest/making-calls#post-parameters-optional) parameter in your call to to the REST API.  The StatusCallback parameter lets you specify a URL that Twilio will make an HTTP request to when the call ends.

To do this in PHP, you can use the options parameter in the create method. This parameter takes an array that lets you add [extra parameters](https://twilio-php.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage/rest/calls.html#adding-extra-call-parameters) to your request:

```
call = $client->account->calls->create(
    '9991231234', // From this number
    '8881231234', // Call this number
    'http://example.com/call.xml',
    array(
        'StatusCallback' => 'http://example.com/callback',
        'StatusCallbackMethod' => 'GET'
    )
);
```

When Twilio makes its request to the URl you've specified as the StatusCallback, you can check the [CallStatus](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/twilio_request#request-parameters-call-status) parameter to see why the call ended.  In the case of no-answer your application can queue up another call to the customer.

```
$callstatus = $_REQUEST["CallStatus"];
if (
    $callstatus == "no-answer" ||
    $callstatus == "busy" ||
    $callstatus == "failed") {
     //caller never answered, line was busy or call failed, so do something about that
}
```

If the caller answers, then you are going to use the [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather) verb to let the customer enter in 1, or some other value.  The Gather verb includes a parameter named [action](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather#attributes-action) that lets you specify a URL that Twilio should request once the user has entered a digit.  You can check the Digits parameter in this request to see if they pressed 1 or some other number.  If  they did not press 1, you can either re-prompt the customer to try entering the digits again or hangup and have your application queue up another call to the customer.

Hope that helps.

Comment: yes, you got the right way, but only 'no-answer' StatusCallback parameter setting, means if no answer then call again. but my issue is if client engaged in first call then second call ringing

Comment: not finding any real example, how to set StatusCallback parameter and how to check CallStatus over here, any real help?

Comment: what programming language are you using?

Comment: expanded my answer with some code snippets that show specifying a StatusCallback URL and then checking what the callstatus is.